# Multiple $form->add() causes failure while handleRequest()

Tags: php, forms, symfony

One short question. Why does it

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder();
$form->add('one');
$form->add('two');
$form->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        die('ok');
    }
```

fail with *Attempted to call an undefined method named "handleRequest" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder".* ?

When I do

```
$form->getForm()->handleRequest($request);
```

I get the same error but instead of *"handleRequest"* it's  *"isSubmitted"*

I also tried to created two forms ($form and $subform) and then nest $form->add($subform) but it results with indends [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9qVQ.png). My task is to go through the loop so I need to add() every field in the array separately.

Comment: Are you calling handleRequest like this: `$form->handleRequest($request);` against your form? Can you show more of the controller code if so?

Comment: yes. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutelly OK to execute multiple ***->add()*** methods on a FormBuilder

In your case **variable $form if a FormBuilder, not a FormInterface**.
So, change your code a bit:

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder();
$formBuilder->add('one');
$formBuilder->add('two');
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

which leads to an error.

Comment: Your issue is the same. Your $form should be called $formBuilder. Then you get form out of it with $form=$formBuilder->getForm(). And then use your $form to submit request, to check if it is valid, etc..

Comment: Write $form=$form->getForm(), before handle request, hope you understand..

Comment: Worked perfectly. P.S. One can be a little confused there isn't $form=... in your answer. If you don't mind changing this in your answer for descendants I will be happy.